# Bring selected calendar date into view

Tags: wpf, calendar

I select a date (not the current date) of a calendar (wpf) by code (C#).
Now I want to bring this selected date into view. How can I solve that? All the time the current date is in view.

Any ideas to that? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the [`DisplayDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydate.aspx) property as well.

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10);
cal.SelectedDate = date;
cal.DisplayDate = date;
```

[image]

You may also want to set the [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.selectionmode.aspx) property to set the range of dates allowed ([`CalendarSelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendarselectionmode.aspx) enumeration).